# cronjob text output cut off

Tags: python, cron, freebsd

I have a cronjob that runs a python script every 2 hours. The script itself can run longer than 2 hours. Thats why I try to detect if the script is already running. The system is FreeBSD machine. I try to do the detection with the following function:

```
def script_already_running(script_name,console_logger,parameter=None):
    """
    checks if the script is already running, this is done by syscall and parsing the output. Parameters of the script can be distinguished as well
    """
    ps = subprocess.Popen("ps aux", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process_strings = ps.stdout.read().decode(encoding="utf-8",errors="strict")
    ps.stdout.close()
    ps.wait()
    console_logger.info(process_strings)
    # print(process_strings)
    # print(script_name)

    if script_name in process_strings and parameter is None:
        script_running = True
    elif script_name in process_strings and parameter is not None:
        if parameter in process_strings:
            script_running = True
        else:
            script_running = False
    else:
        script_running = False

    return script_running
```

this function is called from another script. `script_name` is the name (with path) of the calling script and `console_logger` is a python `logging` object. When I execute everything directly from the shell everything works just fine. The function prints the output of `ps aux` which looks like that (I removed the unnecessary rest)

```
USER    PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ    RSS TT  STAT STARTED       TIME COMMAND
mysql  7225 95.8  1.1 530948 190652  -  IJ   Sun12   3750:03.47 /usr/local/libexec/mysqld --defaults-extra-file=/var/db/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local --datadir=/var/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/db/mysql/test_jail.err --pid-
user  56261 22.8  0.4 195936  60040  0  S+J  22:14      0:02.74 python3 testscript.py (python3.6)
user  50756  0.6  0.5 220976  78068  -  SsJ  21:20      3:25.17 python3 /home/user/immoquery/src/testscript.py (python3.6)
```

So you can see it would never really run because when it starts it would always detect itself running. This is another problem I need to fix in the future. But when I look into the logs that the cronjob creates the output of `ps aux` looks like this:

```
USER    PID %CPU %MEM     VSZ     RSS TT  STAT STARTED       TIME COMMAND
mysql  7225 92,4  1,3  530948  224528  -  IJ   So.12   3179:35,23 /usr/local/li
user  80177 24,9  0,4  196016   60184  -  SsJ  09:20      0:02,83 python3 /home
user  68285  0,5  7,2 1343792 1198784  -  SsJ  07:20      6:46,38 python3 /home
```

An the check delivers `false` because it cannot find the script name in the string return of `ps aux`. The string is somehow cut off.

Here is the content of the cron file:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/zsh
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"

# used to execute immobilienscout24 kaufangebote
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    command
20       7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 *       *       *      python3 /home/user/immoquery/src/testscript.py >> /home/user/testscript.log 2>&1
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this? Why is the process output cut off? Is there a virtual screen size or something involved?

Comment: Use `ps auxww` to get the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep it simple by doing something like:

```
0 */2 * * *  if ! pgrep -f your-script 2>&1 >/dev/null; then your-script; fi
```

The way it works is by checking if the process still running by using `pgrep` and if not it will run your script.

Comment: I tried this which is great as it does not require python level changes. Nevertheless   an `fi` at the end is missing

Answer (score 0):

To get full command-line from `ps`, use `-ww` (two double-us). `pgrep` is a better solution.

Perhaps even better may be to use a lockfile (on a local filesystem, such as under `/var/run` or even `/tmp` somewhere).